# Slick Slider with custom design

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

[image]

Guys, I need your help with Slick. I need to use slick slider like attached image. There is one big slide then 2nd slide with small height and then 3rd slide below 2nd slide with same height. Is this design possible in slick slider?

Comment: What if user want to go to next or previous slide?

Comment: 2nd and 3rd slides will move together and 4th slide will show if user clicks on next button.

Comment: Then use default slick and make slide images like above three images combined.

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/nxt1d8cg/

Comment: and where is your code?

Comment: @CodeBlaze I tried but my 3rd slide is not going below the 2nd slide. It was showing next to 2nd slide.

Comment: @JinuKurian No I need separate slides for both vertical images. I can't place both images in one div.

Comment: @Justcode please check this pen. https://codepen.io/hmajid/pen/NeXNyL